# fog s3 filename without prefix

Tags: amazon-s3, fog

I have been using fog for a while and it works great. I recently encountered a problem where I am traversing through each file in a directory

```
d = S3.directories.get(“XXXXX”, prefix: “XX”)

d.files.each do |f|
puts f.key
end
```

In this case f.key gives me not just the filename but also the prefix, for example it gives: pathtofile/file1.txt. How do I only get file1

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the keys look like filenames, you can use `File.basename`:

```rb
d.files.each do |f|
  puts File.basename(f.key)
end
```